# How can i validate that a text field with time is entered in 15 minute increments using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to validate that a user has entered time in a text field in 15 minute increments. So anything like 8:00, 8:15, 8:30am or 8:45a would be valid. I tried using :contains but it doesn't seem to be working using an OR comparison.

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fuelishways/h0tmvqyc/4/

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <label>Arrival time</label>
    <input type="text" id="arrivalTime"/> <br/>
    <label>Event start time</label>
    <input type="text" id="eventStartTime"/> <br/>
    <label>Event end time</label>
    <input type="text" id="eventEndTime"/> <br/>
    <label>Departure time</label>
    <input type="text" id="departureTime"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var arrivalTime = $('#arrivalTime').val();
    var eventStartTime = $("#eventStartTime").val();
    var eventEndTime = $("#eventEndTime").val();
    var departureTime = $("#departureTime").val();

    if ( arrivalTime.indexOf(':00') === -1 ) || ( arrivalTime.indexOf(':15') === -1 ) || ( arrivalTime.indexOf(':30') === -1 ) || ( arrivalTime.indexOf(':45') === -1 )  {
        alert("There is NOT :00 or :15 or :30 or :45");
        return false;
    }

    alert(arrivalTime + " " + eventStartTime + " " + eventEndTime + " " + departureTime);
    return false; // change to return true when you get it working
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you are using || instead of &&. Your code will error unless it contains :00 AND :15 AND :45 AND :30

```
if ( arrivalTime.indexOf(':00') === -1 ) && ( arrivalTime.indexOf(':15') === -1 ) && ( arrivalTime.indexOf(':30') === -1 ) && ( arrivalTime.indexOf(':45') === -1 )  {
    alert("There is NOT :00 or :15 or :30 or :45");
    return false;
}
```

although a regex may be better to fully qualify it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Garr's answer, you need to put parentheses around all the conditions in the if block:

```
if ( (arrivalTime.indexOf(':00') === -1 ) && ( arrivalTime.indexOf(':15') === -1 ) && ( arrivalTime.indexOf(':30') === -1 ) && ( arrivalTime.indexOf(':45') === -1 ) )
...
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h0tmvqyc/6/)

You may also want to think about utilizing a dropdown list for choosing the times rather than manually entering times - easier to validate and easier for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/0kkzjm6q/.  This solution uses regular expressions.

```
$(function () {
    $("form").submit(function () {
        var arrivalTime = $('#arrivalTime').val();
        var eventStartTime = $("#eventStartTime").val();
        var eventEndTime = $("#eventEndTime").val();
        var departureTime = $("#departureTime").val();

        if (!arrivalTime.trim() || !arrivalTime.match(/:(15|30|45|00)/)) {
            alert("There is NOT :00 or :15 or :30 or :45");
            return false;
        }

        alert('it works!');

        return false;
    });
});
```